# Wrapping consecutive list items in separate groups using jQuery

Tags: jquery, grouping, element, wrapall

I have an unordered list exported by a CMS and need to identify `<li>` elements that have the class .sub and wrap them in a `<ul>`.

I have tried the `wrapAll()` method but that finds all `<li class="sub">` elements and wraps them in one `<ul>`. I need it to maintain seperate groupings.

The exported code is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="sub"></li>
  <li class="sub"></li>
  <li class="sub"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="sub"></li>
  <li class="sub"></li>
  <li class="sub"></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
```

I need it to be:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <ul>
     <li class="sub"></li>
     <li class="sub"></li>
     <li class="sub"></li>
  </ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <ul>
     <li class="sub"></li>
     <li class="sub"></li>
     <li class="sub"></li>
   </ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your final result is invalid HTML. The nested <ul> elements should be within <li> elements.

Comment: @j08691 is correct about the resulting HTML being invalid.  I suggest a rethink on what you're doing.

Answer (score 7):

1. Use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to walk through all `.sub` elements.
2. Ignore elements whose parent has class `wrapped`, using [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass.)
3. Use [`nextUntil(:not(.sub))`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to select all consecutive sub elements (include itself using [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)).
   The given first parameter means: Stop looking forward when the element does not match `.sub`.
4. [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll)

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8MVKu/

For completeness, I have wrapped the set of `<li>` elements in `<li><ul>...</ul></li>` instead of a plain `<ul>`.

Code:

```
$('.sub').each(function() {
   if ($(this.parentNode).hasClass('wrapped')) return;
   $(this).nextUntil(':not(.sub)').andSelf().wrapAll('<li><ul class="wrapped">');
});
$('ul.wrapped').removeClass('wrapped'); // Remove temporary dummy
```

Comment: Awesome, I wish I could give +10

Comment: I was writing the same thing, but appending them to the item before them not a new item. Nice work!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to expand on Rob W's already awesome solution, providing a way to eliminate the temporary wrap class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.sub').filter(':not(li.sub + li.sub)').each(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil(':not(li.sub)').andSelf().wrapAll('<li><ul>');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8yW3/

Edit:  The filter isn't even needed:

```
$('li.sub:not(li.sub + li.sub)').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(li.sub)').andSelf().wrapAll('<li><ul>');
});
```

Comment: Looks good. I don't think that the double loop using filter (filter loops through all elements, and tests them against the selector) is more efficient than a temporary class, though.

Comment: Good point, Rob.  I realized the filter wasn't even necessary, and changed my code in an edit down to a single selector.

Comment: @DanA. Could you please explain the :not(li.sub + li.sub) part? Your solution is clean and works great but I'm trying to understand what that part actually means. I can see that it prevents continued embedding of UL elements, but can't figure out how. Thank you.

Comment: @user1447679 `:not(li.sub + li.sub)` means it's not an `li.sub element` that immediately follows another `li.sub` element.  So basically it starts out by only selecting the first `li.sub` in each grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you should have is this jQuery:

`$('li.sub').wrap('<li><ul>');`

This will properly wrap your `<li>` elements in a new `<ul>` tag while wrapped them within `<li>` tags. The output of your example would then be:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><ul><li class="sub"></li></ul></li>
  <li><ul><li class="sub"></li></ul></li>
  <li><ul><li class="sub"></li></ul></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><ul><li class="sub"></li></ul></li>
  <li><ul><li class="sub"></li></ul></li>
  <li><ul><li class="sub"></li></ul></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
```